# Unwind Segue using performSegueWithIdentifier - Doesn't work - Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, unwind-segue

I am trying to unwind in my button click, after receiving response.

LoginController

```
@IBAction func SignInPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

  if (onSuccess) {
      performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToGlobal", sender: AnyObject?())
  }
}
```

and this is where it comes from (GlobalController).

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "globalToLogin")
    {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            let loginController = segue.destinationViewController as? LoginController
        })
    }
}
```

This one works and as soon as I enter the app (GlobalController is the starting view), I get directed to Login Page. However, when I click on the login button on LoginController, unfortunately it doesn't unwind.

[image]

[image]

When I try to remove these connections and `ctrl + drag` button to exit, it just doesn't do anything.

I couldn't find what I am doing wrong, thus it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here a fews of articles about Unwind, that was super for me, maybe that can help

[Unwind](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/04/23/unwind-segue-set-destination/)

Comment: I read this too but I couldn't figure out how to adapt it in a syntax that I can use in if function